# Use /testfor to make a custom command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Basically, I'm trying to recreate the Faction plugins /f map in my single-player without mods as my PC doesn't run them very well. (I know it sounds strange.) I am trying to use the /testfor to test if I have written '/f map' in chat, and if I have, it would show me a custom generated map.
I don't know how to word this better xD Essentially what I want is for it to test if I have written a command in chat, and if I have, display something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't test exactly for `/f map`, but you can do similar with `/trigger`s.

First, set up the trigger objective:

```
/scoreboard objectives add fmap trigger
```

Then, when people type:

```
/trigger fmap set 1
```

You can select them with `@a[score_fmap_min=1]`, or tell them something like:

```
/tellraw @a[score_fmap_min=1] {"text":"message"}
```

---

As a side note, creating a faction plugin with command blocks is a very ambitious goal, may be worth starting off with something simpler and smaller.

Comment: OK. Thanks :) I decided instead to go simpler with the old fashioned 'command book' method. I now have a working /f map and /f home, and am planning to make more. My problem is just for some reason forge 1.8 just wont run on my pc so im trying to find fun and innovative ways around it xD

Comment: @goldenlord52 More meant that the whole factions thing is going to be complicated, not trigger commands in particular.

Comment: oh, ok. I guess I read it wrong. Anyway, I don't think I'll do the entire faction plugin, just a few commands like /f map, /f home, /f show etc. Not the whole 9 yards though. :)

Comment: You can just use `/trigger fmap`, which is shorter and less obscure.