# Can I use the chat function to activate command blocks?

Tags: minecraft-commands

Is it possible to use the chat function in Minecraft 1.17 to activate a command block, like what most servers do with `/lobby`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Minecraft - How do you make a command block respond to chat?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/330701/minecraft-how-do-you-make-a-command-block-respond-to-chat)

Comment: @Tacoタコス please avoid making duplicate chains.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 I will do my best going forward. :) I can't edit my flag or comment at this point, but [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/240873/use-testfor-to-make-a-custom-command) is the original duplicate.